# [AuthBot]add authentication to azure bot web app

Tags: azure, authentication, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-identity

I'm trying to add some authentication to my bot i followed this article [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp) to do it and i used the AuthBot sample to test it

1- created azure identity provider

2- created connection in azure bot app service for the Azure active directory 2 provider

3- run the bot and test it

and it worked fine and when i tried to use it for first time it redirect me to this page
[image]

and i want to allow the user to request access approval and i followed this doc [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow)
but nothing changed and the bot stile redirect me to this page.
is there is something missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to grant admin consent!
   [image: Grant admin consent to your app]

Comment: Did you test your settings using [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp#test-your-connection)